# How to set Pydantic Extra.allow Extra.ignore on nested class fields

Tags: python, pydantic

How to set `Extra.allow` / `Extra.ignore` on nested class Pydantic fields ?

Basically I want DB schema to allow new fields,  PATCH & POST to forbid and READ to ignore.

This method below works for root properties but setting have no effect on the nested classes

EDIT:  I'm trying to handle schema changes like removing a field without keeping legacy rubbish in the app schema or deleting fields on legacy records in db.

With an example: `FooNest` had 10 fields which are not relevant for the app anymore. Removing them from the app causing the `ValidationError` on `FooInDB` and `FooRead`.

I want to remove dead code from the app but I also want to keep legacy records as they are.

Open for alternative suggestion how to achieve it

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Extra, ValidationError
import pydantic
import pytest


class MyBaseModel(BaseModel):
    class Config:
        extra = Extra.forbid

class FooNest(MyBaseModel):
    boo: int


class FooBase(MyBaseModel):
    root: int
    nest: FooNest


class FooCreate(FooBase, extra=Extra.forbid):
    pass


class FooInDB(FooCreate, MyBaseModel, extra=Extra.allow):
    pass


class FooPatch(FooCreate):
    pass


class FooRead(FooCreate, MyBaseModel, extra=Extra.ignore):
    pass


@pytest.mark.anyio
async def test_pydantic_allow_extra():
    test_no_extra = {"root": 2, "nest": {"boo": 2}}
    test_root_extra = {"root": 2, "nest": {"boo": 2}, "extra": "extra val"}

    test_nested_extra = {"root": 2, "nest": {"boo": 2, "extra": "xxx"}}

    # all should work with without extra
    for obj in [FooInDB, FooRead, FooPatch]:
        parsed = obj.parse_obj(test_no_extra)
        assert parsed.dict() == test_no_extra

    # FooInDB should allow extra
    parsed = FooInDB.parse_obj(test_root_extra)
    assert parsed.dict() == test_root_extra

    # THIS RAISES: ValidationError
    parsed = FooInDB.parse_obj(test_nested_extra)
    assert parsed.dict() == test_nested_extra

    # FooRead should ignore extra
    parsed = FooRead.parse_obj(test_root_extra)
    assert parsed.dict() == test_no_extra

    # THIS RAISES: ValidationError
    parsed = FooRead.parse_obj(test_nested_extra)
    assert parsed.dict() == test_no_extra

    # FooPatch should forbid extra
    with pytest.raises(ValidationError):
        FooPatch.parse_obj(test_root_extra)

    with pytest.raises(ValidationError):
        FooPatch.parse_obj(test_nested_extra)
```

Comment: This is not specific to the `extra` setting; config options never apply recursively to nested models. (Though they are _inherited_.) You need to specify them for each model separately. But this seems like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info). Are you sure you need to handle those differently? What is the purpose of those different settings?

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg : 
 Eg. To handle schema changes like removing a field without keeping legacy rubbish in the app schema or  deleting fields on legacy records in db.

With the  example above:
FooNest had 10 fields which are not relevant. Removing it from the app causing the validationerror in FooInDB  and FooRead. I want to remove  dead code from the app and i want to keep legacy records as they are historic.

Very open for alternative suggestion how to achieve it